# Simple way to draw Hadamard matrices (black/white grids) from external input

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, grids

I want to draw Hadamard matrices of different sizes. This are matrices which have entries +1 and -1 (plus some other properties). Hadamard matrices are often pictured as black/white grids like

[image]

I'm looking for a simple way to draw them with LaTeX. That means there is an input file consisting of +/-1's (or other values, if this is more helpful). LaTeX should convert it to a b/w grid. And it would be nice if I could enter a size for the whole grid and it does automatic resizing. Like in the pictures above.

Comment: I think you will find extremely useful [Drawing a large binary matrix as colored grid in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123719/13304).