# How to add a number at the right of a matrix plot and an additional colored 1 line array below or above

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

From this precedent question [*Drawing a large binary matrix as colored grid in TikZ*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123719/drawing-a-large-binary-matrix-as-colored-grid-in-tikz) I have the following matrix plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents}{matrix.cvs}
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    zero color/.initial=white,
    zero color/.get=\zerocol,
    zero color/.store in=\zerocol,
    one color/.initial=red,
    one color/.get=\onecol,
    one color/.store in=\onecol,
    cell wd/.initial=1ex,
    cell wd/.get=\cellwd,
    cell wd/.store in=\cellwd,
    cell ht/.initial=1ex,
    cell ht/.get=\cellht,
    cell ht/.store in=\cellht,
}

\newcommand{\drawgrid}[2][]{
\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
  \pgfplotstableforeachcolumn#2\as\col{
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{\col}\of#2\as\colcnt{%
      \ifnum\colcnt=0
        \fill[\zerocol]($ -\pgfplotstablerow*(0,\cellht) + \col*(\cellwd,0) $) rectangle+(\cellwd,\cellht);
      \fi
      \ifnum\colcnt=1
        \fill[\onecol]($ -\pgfplotstablerow*(0,\cellht) + \col*(\cellwd,0) $) rectangle+(\cellwd,\cellht);
      \fi
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\medskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% read the file
\pgfplotstableread{matrix.cvs}{\matrixfile}


\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
        \drawgrid[zero color=orange, 
          one color=violet,
          cell ht=0.75em,
          cell wd=0.75em]{\matrixfile}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which plots a 50 columns matrix:

[image]

I would like to add a number to each row of the matrix

```
0.0293
0.0211
0.0165
0.0163
0.0134
0.0382
0.0150
0.8501
```

and (aligned) add a matrix plot of one row at the bottom with white (0) to black (1) indicating these weights.

```
0.2833
0.0336
0.7766
0.0468
0.0228
0.0143
0.6877
0.0700
0.1287
0.6659
0.7123
0.0143
0.0143
0.6325
0.8049
0.7282
0.1624
0.6346
0.0564
0.0176
0.0143
0.0271
0.6463
0.7268
0.4798
0.1637
0.0297
0.3054
0.5039
0.0246
0.7140
0.3091
0.4256
0.3418
0.6493
0.0508
0.0143
0.2927
0.0291
0.6622
0.0143
0.0177
0.1610
0.1287
0.7471
0.0563
0.0143
0.3275
0.6773
0.5992
```

to get something like this:

[image]

(I have not completed the 1-row matrix of greys)

To distinguish better the rows and columns it would be a feature of the plot to control the white separation lines of the matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents}{matrix.cvs}
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    zero color/.initial=white,
    zero color/.get=\zerocol,
    zero color/.store in=\zerocol,
    one color/.initial=red,
    one color/.get=\onecol,
    one color/.store in=\onecol,
    cell wd/.initial=1ex,
    cell wd/.get=\cellwd,
    cell wd/.store in=\cellwd,
    cell ht/.initial=1ex,
    cell ht/.get=\cellht,
    cell ht/.store in=\cellht,
    xlabels/.store in=\myxlabels,
    ylabels/.store in=\myylabels,
}
\newcommand{\drawgrid}[2][]{
\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
  \pgfplotstableforeachcolumn#2\as\col{
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{\col}\of#2\as\colcnt{%
      \ifnum\colcnt=0
        \fill[\zerocol]($ (0,-\pgfplotstablerow*\cellht) + (\col*\cellwd,0) $) rectangle+(\cellwd,\cellht);
      \fi
      \ifnum\colcnt=1
        \fill[\onecol]($ (0,-\pgfplotstablerow*\cellht) + (\col*\cellwd,0) $) rectangle+(\cellwd,\cellht);
      \fi
    }
  }
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{#2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numcols}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \draw[white] (0,\cellht) grid[xstep=\cellwd,ystep=\cellht]
     (\cellwd*\numcols,\cellht-\cellht*\numrows); %
  \foreach \Z [count=\Y] in \myylabels   
   {\node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,scale=0.7] at 
    (\cellwd*\numcols,1.5*\cellht-\cellht*\Y) {\Z};}
  \foreach \Z [count=\X,evaluate=\Z as \CC using {int(\Z*100)}] in \myxlabels    
   {\fill[black!\CC]  
   (-\cellwd+\X*\cellwd,0.5*\cellht-\cellht*\numrows)
    rectangle ++ (\cellwd,-\cellht);
    \node[anchor=west,rotate=-90,font=\sffamily,scale=0.7] at 
    (-0.5*\cellwd+\X*\cellwd,-0.5*\cellht-\cellht*\numrows) {\Z};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\medskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% read the file
\pgfplotstableread{matrix.cvs}{\matrixfile}


\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
        \drawgrid[zero color=orange, 
          one color=violet,
          cell ht=0.75em,
          cell wd=0.75em,
          xlabels={0.2833,0.0336,0.7766,0.0468,0.0228,0.0143,0.6877,0.0700,0.1287,0.6659,0.7123,0.0143,0.0143,0.6325,0.8049,0.7282,0.1624,0.6346,0.0564,0.0176,0.0143,0.0271,0.6463,0.7268,0.4798,0.1637,0.0297,0.3054,0.5039,0.0246,0.7140,0.3091,0.4256,0.3418,0.6493,0.0508,0.0143,0.2927,0.0291,0.6622,0.0143,0.0177,0.1610,0.1287,0.7471,0.0563,0.0143,0.3275,0.6773,0.5992},
          ylabels={0.0293,0.0211,0.0165,0.0163,0.0134,0.0382,0.0150,0.8501}]{\matrixfile}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that the figure is a bit too wide for the given page parameters, meaning that you may want to make the page wider, the figure smaller or to rotate the figure.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to test both alternatives, reduce the size and make it in one page (without other floats or text) rotated 90. I noticed that the figure is not centered with the words `Figure 1: caption`. Do you know how to arrange it?.

Comment: @user1993416 I already upvoted it.