# Drawing a pixel diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

A pixel diagram is a way to visualize a graph, or even the non-zero entries in a matrix.  It is typically used to help visualize [graphons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphon). I am trying to use Tikz to draw these diagrams.  An example can be seen below (taken from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322670484_The_control_of_arbitrary_size_networks_of_linear_systems_via_graphon_limits_An_initial_investigation))

[image]

So the idea is as follows: for a square `n x n` matrix, draw an `n x n` grid, and make the `i-jth` pixel black if the `i-jth` element of the matrix is non-zero (or there is an edge between nodes `i` and `j`).

Is it possible to enter a data file containing the matrix data and have tikz generate the pixel diagram?  I am very much a tikz novice and don't even know where to begin here...

thanks!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157080/can-tikz-create-pixel-art-images.  Is it perhaps a duplicate of your question?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes - Thanks for the link! this is indeed very close to what I am after, so I will study it and see how it goes!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123728, which really plots it from a data file. There is also `matrix plot` which comes with `pgfplots`.